# Android GridLayout Border

Tags: java, android

I am working on a Tic-Tac-Toe.

However, i want to add a border to my `GridLayout(Board)`

Here is the following code of my gridLayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/boardGrid"
            app:columnCount="3"
            app:rowCount="3"
            app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
            android:background="@drawable/burledwood"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanx for your response but unfortunately, its about gridview, not gridlayout, 2 different things, big difference :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create A **border.xml** file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#00fb9a"/>
      <stroke
        android:color="#5d05ff"
        android:width="3dp"/>
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

Apply that background file as background drawable in GridLayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/boardGrid"
            app:columnCount="3"
            app:rowCount="3"
            app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
```

Comment: let me try... wait

Comment: oh no... i am setting the background with my script as there are multiple ones.... so this wont work... i want custom border put to the gridLayout

Comment: create a custom adapter then and use the same border.xml in the main view of custom adapter xml

Comment: sounds good...could you help by providing some basic code to give me an idea and overview please sir? :)

Comment: you can use custom gridview for this.

Comment: please show me some overview please... i am really confused :"(

Comment: go to this link http://www.android-examples.com/display-divider-border-between-gridview-items-in-android/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126669/discussion-between-androidhacker-and-rohit-kumar).